# Get entities from given keys in Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to query entities from a list of keys? Something like:

```
datastore.createQuery('kind').filter('__key__', '=', keyArray)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call Datastore.fetch or Datastore.get. Below is the JavaDoc for the latest version of the API.

http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.17.1/apidocs/com/google/cloud/datastore/Datastore.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sai. I'm using the Node client. Didn't find the `fetch` method, but there is a `get` one: `datastore.get(keys, callback);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "lookup" endpoint via Datastore's REST API. See documentation linked below:

[Cloud Datastore - Method: projects.lookup](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/lookup)